# error : Method not found: 'System.String EnvDTE._DTE.get_Version()

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, mysql-workbench, visual-studio-2022

[image]

hai
i'm working on the mysql with entityframework mvc …getting error while creating the edmx in entityframe work.used visual studio 2022 version
i'm getting error while select the mysql database name and click 'ok'button …this is the error "Method not found: 'System.String EnvDTE._DTE.get_Version()"…please coluld you please help anyone to me